# Library mode in vitejs: How should I manage external dependencies?

Tags: javascript, rollupjs, vite

Let's say I'm building a library with a few dependencies: react, moment, lodash, and uuid, and I want to distribute this in both ES and UMD format.

I'm also wary of the final bundle size of the user's application.

React should go into `rollupOptions.external`, since it requires a single React instance is run in the application. But what about the rest?

In my mind, the library should avoid including *any* external dependencies, since these risk being duplicated by the library user's application if they were to use the same dependencies.

Thus, I imagine my `vite.config.js` file to look like this:

```
const path = require("path");
const { defineConfig } = require("vite");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  build: {
    // Let the library user control minification in their own bundler
    minify: false,
    sourcemap: true,
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "source/index.js"),
      name: "my-tiny-library",
      fileName: (format) => `my-tiny-library.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // Add _all_ external dependencies here
      external: ["moment", "uuid", "lodash", "react"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          moment: "moment",
          uuid: "uuid",
          lodash: "lodash"
          react: "react"
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

package.json should contain all dependencies listed in externals as `dependencies`, and *not* `devDependencies` or `peerDependencies`.

The main con I see with this is that anybody using UMD bundles would need to include additional script tags with all dependencies from other sources, e.g: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>`, and that these would not be tree shaked, thus requiring larger bundles. That said, I think that's an okay tradeoff.

Do you agree with this approach, or do you recommend something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

> Add *all* external dependencies here

i do this with

```js
import pkg from './package.json';

/** @type {import("vite").UserConfig} */
export default {
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {}),
    },
  },
};
```